# segue from searchResultsTableView

Tags: xcode4.5, segue, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I currently have a searchdisplaycontroller set up and working. The original table view has a segue set up for the title and image to be passed to a detail view. I would like this segue to happen from the search display controller but this is not happening? I know this is possible but can't seem to get it to work? My code is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        [self.detailViewController setDetailItem:[[contentsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]
                                                  objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailview"]) {
           self.detailViewController=segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}

@end
```

and in the detail view to set it all up:

```
- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.navigationItem.title = [self.detailItem objectForKey:@"name"];
        [self.detailImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.detailItem[@"image"]]];
    }
}
```

I would be very grateful for any help in solving this issue :)

Comment: Ok another update to anyone reading this...
 
I have changed
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 
    To
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[mainTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
in cellForRowAtIndexPath and this now allows me to segue but when I do it will keep the order of the mainTableView rather than that of the search results so getting closer but not quite there! Also I have a grouped table, is it possible to get the search results to mirror this syling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Segue from a Search Display Controller by calling performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: from tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     // Get the UITableViewCell that was selected
     UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

     // Then this will call prepareForSegue:sender: with selectedCell as sender
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailview" sender:selectedCell];  
}
```

Then on prepareForSegue:sender: you set your destinationViewController properties

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailview"]) {

       // Set your destinationViewController properties here

    }
}
```